# source.developers.google.com authentication issue

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I am trying to check out the code base on my Google App Engine code repository into PyCharm.

Its asking me to authenticate, which is when I supply my gmail creds and I can't check it out.

I am getting authentication issues.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Your password for your Google Code repository is not the same as your Gmail password. You can find your Google Code password on [this page](https://code.google.com/hosting/settings).